# Python requests: Download only html pages to skip .exe, .zip .jpg etc

Tags: python, python-requests

I do i check content type or prevent python requests from downloading pages I do not want due to it's mime type. I could easily check extension which I did in actual code but then a link like http://holo-pack.com.tw/download.phpx?soft=ea70 with 1gb size file of .exe, .zip would delay my script, and i really do not want these files.

Is there a way to skip?

```
a = [
"http://holo-pack.com.tw/download.phpx?soft=ea70", # this is an exe, it could be .jpg or .mp3, or .zip etc
"http://holo-pack.com.tw/",  # html/php/txt/asp/jsp/cfm/ etc
"http://example.com/page/i.asp?a=1", # html/php/txt/asp/jsp/cfm/ etc

]

for i in a:
    r = request.get(i)
    cont = r.header['content-type'] # contains the type. I want to avoid 
none not html supported file.
    if cont == 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream': #  I need to skip before download
        continue
    else:
        print r.text
```

Comment: Compliant servers will respond to the HEAD method, which only returns the headers associated with the resource, and not the resource itself. To test this use `request.head()` instead of get

Comment: @RishavKundu sending head to "http://holo-pack.com.tw/download.phpx?soft=ea70" returns its content type as text/html

Comment: Yes, the response is a 404. Too bad people don’t write servers more carefully.

Comment: @RishavKundu response code is: 301